# How do i check my viewcontroller is displaying now or not?

Tags: ios, objective-c, view, uiviewcontroller

I want to write my `viewcontroller` status into a `plist` (something like what my `viewcontroller` is currently displaying, or that I moved to another view from there), so that when I check my `plist` I can see that at a given time I was using that `viewcontroller` (eg: at 2pm I was using `viewcontroller1` and 2.05pm I was using `viewcontroller2`). How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `ViewController1`.

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    // code to save start time in plist for viewcontroller 1
}
```

when it switches from a view u can get it from

```
-(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
    // code to save end time in plist for viewcontroller 1
}
```

In `ViewController2`.

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    // code to save start time in plist for viewcontroller 2
}
```

when it switches from a view u can get it from

```
-(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
    // code to save end time in plist for viewcontroller 2
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Accessing plist each time is not good since it eats time and it affects the performance of the app. So Keep the log in a dictionary(use **Singleton pattern** to share the dictionary between view controllers)

Use like following in **viewWillAppear** of each view controller

```
[viewControllerStatus setObject:NSStringFromClass([self class]) forKey:[NSDate date]];
```

Finally write this dictionary into plist in `applicationDidEnterBackground:` or `applicationWillTerminate:`

Answer (score 0):

Use `viewWillAppear` method to log into the `PLIST` file.